# Proving the Chebychev inequality for infinity norm - spot a mistake?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

I noticed that the Chebyshev inequality is always stated in $L^p$ norm. Doesn't it straightforwardly generalise to $L^{\infty}$?

If we use the infinity (semi-)norm and restrict ourselves to functions that have $||X||_{\infty} < \infty$ we could proceed as follows: For some $\epsilon>0$ we have $[||X||_{\infty}> \epsilon] = \frac{||X||_{\infty}^2}{||X||_{\infty}^{2}} [||X||_{\infty}> \epsilon]$ where I am using $[.]$ as the indicator function for sets described therein (De Finetti notation).

Then, if the inequality is true, we have
$[||X||_{\infty}> \epsilon] \leq \frac{||X||_{\infty}^2}{\epsilon^2} [||X||_{\infty}> \epsilon]$.

Now, we can integrate both sides to find
$\mathbb{P}[||X||_{\infty}> \epsilon] \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}||X||_{\infty}^2}{\epsilon^2}$ where leaving out the indicator $[||X||_{\infty}> \epsilon]$ is permitted because we are modifying our integrand on a set of measure $0$.

Can someone spot a mistake? This derivation strikes me as a useful device to establish uniform convergence whenever something about the finite variance is known.